# Where does the default JButton color (gradient) originate within Java?

Tags: java

When you create a JButton (or JPanel) you can change the background color (setBackground). Before changing the color however, you have a sort of gradient background. where does that come from?

Comment: It comes from The Oracle: [How to Set the Look And Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: The "content" is supplied by the look and feel